# How do I pass arguments to a contract-constructor with web3Js (>=version 1.0)

Tags: contract-development, myetherwallet

I was on https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts and wanted to deploy a contract.

[image]

It worked with a contract with a constructor without arguments, but my contract constructor looks like this:

```
  function CrowdFunding(address _arg1, uint256 _arg2, uint256 _arg3) public {
    arg1 = _arg1;
    arg2 = _arg2;
    arg3 = _arg3;
  }
```

But how do I pass my arguments (arg1, arg2 and arg3)? I'm using web3JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **a newer version of web3** (version 1.0.0 for example):

```
 // example solidity code
 function ContractName(address _arg1, uint256 _arg2, uint256 _arg3) public {
    arg1 = _arg1;
    arg2 = _arg2;
    arg3 = _arg3;
  }
```

Use **web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter()** or **web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters()** to encode your parameters and concatenate them at the end of your bytecode.

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const solc = require("solc");

// compile the solidity code
let compiled = solc.compile(source);

// save public interface of contract
let abi = JSON.parse(compiled.contracts[":ContractName"].interface)

// create var with contract
let CrowdFunding = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

let bytecodeWithParameters = compiled.contracts[':ContractName'].bytecode + web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256'], ['0x08cf02070bb9f167556c677da58e6678bbe871fc', '100000000000000000', '10000']).slice(2);
// slice(2) because we want to remove the '0x' at the beginning.
```

Now, you can enter **bytecodeWithParameters** on https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts to deploy (with arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let fs = require("fs");
let Web3 = require("web3");

let web3 = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);

async function send(transaction) {
    let gas = await transaction.estimateGas({from: PUBLIC_KEY});
    let options = {
        to  : transaction._parent._address,
        data: transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas : gas
    };
    let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
}

async function deploy(contractName, contractArgs) {
    let abi = fs.readFileSync(contractName + ".abi").toString();
    let bin = fs.readFileSync(contractName + ".bin").toString();
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    let handle = await send(contract.deploy({data: "0x" + bin, arguments: contractArgs}));
    console.log(`${contractName} contract deployed at address ${handle.contractAddress}`);
    return new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), handle.contractAddress);
}
```

Usage example:

```
let crowdFunding = await deploy("CrowdFunding", [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```